# sap.m.IconTabFilter: How to display full text with icon?

Tags: sapui5

I want to display `IconTabBar` with full texts and icons. How to fix it? With `showAll="true"`, full text is used but without icon.

[image: icon tab filter with separated text]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make text appear fully in IconTabBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423601/how-to-make-text-appear-fully-in-icontabbar)

Answer (score 0):

showall does not work in this way. It has nothing to do with wrapping of text items.

> > Form the API documentation for sap.m.IconTabFilter: "Enables special
> >     visualization for disabled filter (show all items).
>
> Default value is false."

Possible Solution: Use CSS to increase the size of the single IconTabFilters or disable the text wrapping using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If your labels get truncated, consider using shorter labels or text tabs (without icons), as text tabs cannot get truncated.

The text-only variant is one of the most common types. It allows longer labels, and can also display counters above the text to indicate the number of items on the tab page.

Unlike all other tab variants, **the labels do not get truncated**. The full text is always shown.

Answer (score -2):

```
            <IconTabBar>
            <items>
            <IconTabFilter icon="sap-icon://hint">
            <l:SimpleForm  minWidth="1024">

            <core:Title text="Address"/>
            <Label text="Name"/>
            <Text text="{BuyerName}"/>
            <Label text="Created At"/>
            <Text text="{CreatedAt}"/>
            <Label text="Created By Bp"/>
            <Text text="{CreatedByBp}"/>

            </l:SimpleForm>
            </IconTabFilter>
            <IconTabFilter icon="sap-icon://attachment">
            <l:SimpleForm id="SupplierForm" minWidth="1024">
             <Label text="status"/> 
            <Label text="Name" />
            <Input value="{BuyerName}">
            </Input>
            </l:SimpleForm>
            </IconTabFilter>
            </items>
            </IconTabBar>
```