# How to make text appear fully in IconTabBar?

Tags: sapui5

I am using [IconTabBar](https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.m.IconTabBar) in my application and the text (heading for the tab) is not displaying fully. Half of the text gets cut.

```xml
<IconTabBar class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
  <items>
    <IconTabFilter
      icon="sap-icon://approvals"
      text="Set Values for Mass Change" design="Horizontal"
    >
      <mvc:XMLView viewName="abc.view.selectionPage"/>
    </IconTabFilter>
    <IconTabSeparator icon="sap-icon://open-command-field"/>
  </items>
</IconTabBar>
```

So here the text, which should be "Set Values for Mass Change", is output as "Set Values for Mass..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is cut in half due to two properties set in the classes :

1. sapMITBHorizontalWrapper ( for the Wrapper Div) and
2. sapMITBHorizontal.sapMITBFilter>.sapMITBHorizontalWrapper>.sapMITBText ( Max-width for the displayed Text )

Here, max-width is set to 7.5rem and text-overflow is set to : ellipsis.

Somehow, its not possible to add a class to IconTabFilter (bad) but you can add class to IconTabBar. So, to solve this I've increased the max-width to 10rem. You can increase and decrease max-width to suit your requirements.

Below is the css code:

```
.myWidth .sapMITBHorizontalWrapper {
    max-width: 10rem;
}

.myWidth .sapMITBHorizontal.sapMITBFilter>.sapMITBHorizontalWrapper>.sapMITBText {
    max-width: 10rem;
}
```

View:

```
<IconTabBar class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding myWidth">
                    <items>
                        <IconTabFilter id='myId' icon="sap-icon://approvals" class='' text="Set Values for Mass Change" design="Horizontal">
                           <!--  <mvc:XMLView viewName="abc.view.selectionPage"/> -->
                        </IconTabFilter>
                        <IconTabSeparator icon="sap-icon://open-command-field"/>
                         <IconTabFilter  icon="sap-icon://approvals" class='' text="Short Text" design="Horizontal">
                           <!--  <mvc:XMLView viewName="abc.view.selectionPage"/> -->
                        </IconTabFilter>
                        <IconTabFilter  icon="sap-icon://approvals" class='' text="Shorter" design="Horizontal">
                           <!--  <mvc:XMLView viewName="abc.view.selectionPage"/> -->
                        </IconTabFilter>

                        <IconTabFilter  icon="sap-icon://approvals" class='' text="This is a Big text." design="Horizontal">
                           <!--  <mvc:XMLView viewName="abc.view.selectionPage"/> -->
                        </IconTabFilter>
                        <IconTabFilter  icon="sap-icon://approvals" class='' text="Lil" design="Horizontal">
                           <!--  <mvc:XMLView viewName="abc.view.selectionPage"/> -->
                        </IconTabFilter>
                    </items>
                </IconTabBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text becomes too long, consider to display **texts only** aligning with Fiori Design Guidelines:

> If your labels get truncated, consider using shorter labels or text tabs (without icons), as text tabs cannot get truncated. [[source]](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/icontabbar/#icon-tabs)

Internally, the `IconTabHeader` (the header control for `IconTabBar`) then applies the style class `sapMITBTextOnly`<sup>[src](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/f3592fd1ffdc2a085176744ae9ffad4b439845df/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/IconTabHeaderRenderer.js#L89-L91)</sup> which **excludes** `max-width`.<sup>[src](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/0e9419da28c3a8c5f98de7bed1317b849676efaa/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/themes/base/IconTabBar.less#L214)</sup>

```xml
<IconTabBar>
  <items>
    <IconTabFilter text="products" count="20"/>
    <IconTabFilter text="jkjlsdfjalkfak awfgvbf uwewrw fwkjfv dqw qlkwejqwklejdifsuvnvxdlcmeq" count="4"/>
    <!-- ... -->
  </items>
</IconTabBar>
```

[image]

Since the length is basically limitless, it's still recommended to ensure that the texts do not become too long.

Answer (score 0):

try below

```css
.sapMITBFilter .sapMITBText {
  width: 10rem;
}

.sapMITBTab {
  width: 10rem;
}
```